# how to notify adapter when any value in the listrow has been changed from any activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am having a fragment with recyclerview, the data in this recyclerview is being added using RecyclerViewAdapter.

Now I am having a Like, Comment option in each row of recyclerview and also display comment count in each row. When I click on Comment Option of any of the row, a new Activity, listing all the comments get started. Now if I add some more comments or delete any comment then that comment count get changed.

Now, If I go back from this activity to the fragment, the comment count should be changed for that row. How can I achieve this, please help me if you have any idea here.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

read notifyDatasetChanged and notifyItemchanged

Comment: I have read notifyDatasetChanged and notifyItemchanged, but I am not able to get the position of the row for which the comment option get clicked, can you please give me an idea here.

Thank you so much in advanced.

Comment: position is coming as a parameter of click listener, and for notifyDatasetChanged no position is required

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped me alot. Thanks.. :)